# Why is Model.where(id: 4) different than Model.where(:id == 4)?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

When typing into the rails console

```
@draft_variables = DraftVariable.where(draft_id: params[:id].to_i)
```

it returns all rows with the matching ID, while typing

```
@draft_variables = DraftVariable.where(:draft_id == params[:id].to_i)
```

returns all rows that have any ID.

Why is this? I'm on Rails 4.1, ruby 2.1.0.

Comment: You might be trying to do `@draft_variables = DraftVariable.where("draft_id == params[:id].to_i")`.. something like this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following statement

```
@draft_variables = DraftVariable.where(:draft_id == params[:id].to_i)
```

evaluates to

```
@draft_variables = DraftVariable.where(false)
```

Which in turn results in query

```
SELECT `draft_variables`.* FROM `draft_variables`
```

So it returns all the records

Comment: How can it be `true` ?

Comment: still not convinced.. if where is `false` no row should be selected, if always `true`,then all rows. But how does it evaluate to `true` ?